# Xamarin Forms - NavigationPage.TitleView doesn't work on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a simple (File->New Project) XF app that won't show the `NavigationPage.TitleView` content for iOS.  Android works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/JohnLivermore/SampleXamarinApp/tree/navigationheaderissue).

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   Text="Page Title" />
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the output...

[image]

I also tried a StackLayout, same results...

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   Text="Page Title" />
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: is your ContentPage contained in a NavigationPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Jason` mentioned in the comment, 
[NavigationPage.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.titleviewproperty?view=xamarin-forms) is a part of `Navigation Bar` in `NavigationPage`. To customize the `TitleView`, you should first create a `NavigationPage` :

```
public App ()
{
  MainPage = new NavigationPage (new Page1());
}
```

Then set the `TitleView` in the ContentPage:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Page Title" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Refer : [Hierarchical Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)